# Compare rows, based on the value (i.e. date and status columns) insert a new row in SQL Server 2012 or SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I need to compare rows in a single table for three different columns "MSName", "MSStatus" and "MSDate". "ID" is the location Identifier and "MSName" is a column for several milestones to be completed on a specific location. Please ignore the "CalcSAED" column for now as I have created it as part of my solution. Please refer to the screenshot below for sample table:

Rules:

Condition 1: IF ( MSName = "FTA" AND MSStatus = "Actual" THEN "INSERT a new row with same column values for ("ID,"SName", "MSStatus", "MSDate") but MSName should "SAEDR",

Condition 2:   ELSE IF( MSNAME ="Acc AAA" AND MSStatus ="Actual" AND Condtion 1 = FALSE THEN "INSERT a new row with same column values for ("ID,"SName", "MSStatus", "MSDate") but MSName should "SAEDR",

Condition 3: ELSE IF ( MSNAME ="SAED" AND MSStatus ="Actual" AND Condition 1 AND Condition 2 = FALSE THEN "INSERT a new row with same column values for ("ID,"SName", "MSStatus", "MSDate") but MSName should "SAEDR",

ELSE NEXT

[Rules Flow Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9xxZ.png)

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/227Ty.png)

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE D1 (

             ID varchar(2)
            ,SName varchar(50)
            ,MSName varchar(50)
            ,MSStatus Varchar(10)
            ,MSDate Date
            ,CalcSAED varchar(10)
    )

INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A1', 'Melbourne', 'FTA', 'Actual', '2016-02-12', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A1', 'Melbourne', 'Acc AAA', 'Pending', '2016-02-13', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A1', 'Melbourne', 'SAED', 'Pending', '2016-02-14', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A2', 'Melbourne1', 'FTA', 'Pending', '2016-02-15', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A2', 'Melbourne1', 'Acc AAA', 'Actual', '2016-02-12', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A2', 'Melbourne1', 'SAED', 'Pending', '2016-02-16', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A3', 'Melbourne2', 'FTA', 'Pending', '2016-02-17', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A3', 'Melbourne2', 'Acc AAA', 'Pending', '2016-02-12', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A3', 'Melbourne2', 'SAED', 'Actual', '2016-02-11', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A4', 'Melbourne3', 'FTA', 'Pending', '2016-02-10', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A4', 'Melbourne3', 'Acc AAA', 'Pending', '2016-02-19', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A4', 'Melbourne3', 'SAED', 'Pending', '2016-02-16', NULL)

    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A5', 'Melbourne4', 'FTA', 'Actual', '2016-02-13', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A5', 'Melbourne4', 'Acc AAA', 'Actual', '2016-02-16', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A5', 'Melbourne4', 'SAED', 'Actual', '2016-02-18', NULL)

    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A6', 'Melbourne5', 'FTA', 'Actual', '2016-02-13', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A6', 'Melbourne5', 'Acc AAA', 'Pending', '2016-02-16', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A6', 'Melbourne5', 'SAED', 'Actual', '2016-02-18', NULL)


    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A7', 'Melbourne6', 'FTA', 'Actual', '2016-02-13', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A7', 'Melbourne6', 'Acc AAA', 'Actual', '2016-02-16', NULL)
    INSERT INTO D1 VALUES ('A7', 'Melbourne6', 'SAED', 'Actual', '2016-02-18', NULL)
```

My lousy solution so far:

1. Create a Column called "CalcSAED" and update it as "True" For valid
2. UNION two select statements for "True" values and change their "MSName" to "SAEDR" and Complete Original table.

PS: I am not even sure if my query is 100% reliable but so far working with the sample table.

My solution code:

```
UPDATE D1 SET CalcSAED = NULL


    UPDATE D1
       SET CalcSAED = 'True'

      FROM D1 
INNER JOIN D1 AS D2
        ON D2.ID = D1.ID
INNER JOIN D1 AS D3
        ON D1.ID = D3.ID 
     WHERE (D1.MSName LIKE 'FTA' AND D1.MSStatus LIKE 'Actual')
        OR ((D1.MSName LIKE 'Acc AAA' AND D1.MSStatus LIKE 'Actual') AND (D2.MSName LIKE 'FTA' AND D2.MSStatus NOT LIKE 'Actual'))
        OR (D1.MSName LIKE 'SAED' AND D1.MSStatus LIKE 'Actual') AND  (D2.MSName LIKE 'Acc AAA' AND D2.MSStatus NOT LIKE 'Actual') AND (D3.MSName LIKE 'FTA' AND D3.MSStatus NOT LIKE 'Actual') 

GO

    ;WITH TempCTE(ID, SName, MSName, MSStatus, MSDate, CalcSAED) AS

        (


            SELECT ID, SName, MSName = 'SAED-R', MSStatus, MSDate, CalcSAED 
            FROM D1
            WHERE CalcSAED LIKE 'True'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT ID, SName, MSName , MSStatus, MSDate, CalcSAED 
            FROM D1



        )

        SELECT * FROM TempCTE
        ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Basically, I am using SSIS package to import data from SQL Server database onto a different SQL Server. Currently, I am planning to run this query at the end of SSIS package execution.I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. So, please any suggestions and advice on this will be highly appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your destination table is the source table ?

Comment: Nope. This is going from source to a different destination table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i work with the result that you shared in your question the components that i use are :

**- OLEDB SOURCE**

**- MULTICAST**

**- CONDITIONAL SPLIT**

**- 3 DERIVED COLUMNS**

**- UNION ALL**

**- SORT**

**- OLEDB DESTINATION**

This a picture of your data flow :

[image]

In the **component Conditional Split** i add the 3 condition see the picture as bellow:

[image]

Then i add **3 Derived Columns** to remplace the value of the row with te value with do you need see the picture as bellow for more details

[image]

I did the same thing with all `Derived Column`

In the end add `a sort Component` see the picutre as bellow

[image]
Finaly : add your `Destination table` and this is end result :

```
  ID    SName   MSName  MSStatus    MSDate  CalcSAED
A1  Melbourne   Acc AAA Pending 2016-02-13  NULL
A1  Melbourne   FTA Actual  2016-02-12  NULL
A1  Melbourne   SAED    Pending 2016-02-14  NULL
A1  Melbourne   SAEDR   Actual  2016-02-12  NULL
A2  Melbourne1  Acc AAA Actual  2016-02-12  NULL
A2  Melbourne1  FTA Pending 2016-02-15  NULL
A2  Melbourne1  SAED    Pending 2016-02-16  NULL
A2  Melbourne1  SAEDR   Actual  2016-02-12  NULL
A3  Melbourne2  Acc AAA Pending 2016-02-12  NULL
A3  Melbourne2  FTA Pending 2016-02-17  NULL
A3  Melbourne2  SAED    Actual  2016-02-11  NULL
A3  Melbourne2  SAEDR   Actual  2016-02-11  NULL
A4  Melbourne3  Acc AAA Pending 2016-02-19  NULL
A4  Melbourne3  FTA Pending 2016-02-10  NULL
A4  Melbourne3  SAED    Pending 2016-02-16  NULL
A5  Melbourne4  Acc AAA Actual  2016-02-16  NULL
A5  Melbourne4  FTA Actual  2016-02-13  NULL
A5  Melbourne4  SAED    Actual  2016-02-18  NULL
A5  Melbourne4  SAEDR   Actual  2016-02-16  NULL
A6  Melbourne5  Acc AAA Pending 2016-02-16  NULL
A6  Melbourne5  FTA Actual  2016-02-13  NULL
A6  Melbourne5  SAED    Actual  2016-02-18  NULL
A6  Melbourne5  SAEDR   Actual  2016-02-18  NULL
A7  Melbourne6  Acc AAA Actual  2016-02-16  NULL
A7  Melbourne6  FTA Actual  2016-02-13  NULL
A7  Melbourne6  SAED    Actual  2016-02-18  NULL
A7  Melbourne6  SAEDR   Actual  2016-02-18  NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Looks like just what I need. Let me try your solution  . Will update you soon :)

Comment: Hey! a quick one. In the result table for the ID A6 & A7 what if I want only one insertion of SAEDR in accordance with the rules given? I think if I tweak the conditions it should work?

Comment: Works fine! Thanks heaps for your help. You're a champ!

Comment: ok glad to help you !!  do you want remove the duplicate value of `SAEDR` ?

Comment: you welcome please if my answer solve your problems please check my answer thanks